# Assert false not stopping the execution of Tests if we have multiple class extending Specification

Tags: groovy, junit, spock

Assume we have Parent and Child class were we have extended Specification in Parent and Child has extended Parent. Hence Child is also becames Specification.

```
//Parent
@Stepwise
class Parent extends Specification{
@Shared 
String name

def setupSpec(){
    println "inside setupSpec"
}
def setup(){

    println "inside SetUp"
}
def "testMethodOne"(){
    given:
    println "inside parent testmethodOne"
    assert 1==2


}
def "testMethodTwo"(){
    given:
    println "parent testmethodTwo"

}
def cleanup(){

    println " inside CleanUp"
}
def cleanupSpec(){
    println "inside cleanSpec"

}
```

}
//Child Class

```
//Child
@Stepwise
class Child extends Parent {

def "testMethod"(){
    given:
    println "inside child testmethod"

}
def "testMethodtwo"(){
    given:
    println "inside child testmethodTeo"

 }
}
```

Now if we are executing Child Class then assert will fail in the Parents testMethodOne and Since we are using @Stepwise then entire test should not have executed after failure of assertion. Interestingly test method of parent is not getting executed where as all the method is child is getting executed which not execute as assert got failed.

Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Do you have assertion processing turned on when you compile?  Some IDEs/compilers have it off by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package spock.lang;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.ExtensionAnnotation;
import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.StepwiseExtension;

/**
 * Indicates that a spec's feature methods should be run sequentially
 * in their declared order (even in the presence of a parallel spec runner),
 * always starting from the first method. If a method fails, the remaining
 * methods will be skipped. Feature methods declared in super- and subspecs
 * are not affected.
 *
 * <p><tt>&#64;Stepwise</tt> is useful for specs with
 * (logical) dependencies between methods. In particular, it helps to avoid
 * consecutive errors after a method has failed, which makes it easier to
 * understand what really went wrong.
 *
 * @author Peter Niederwieser
 */
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtensionAnnotation(StepwiseExtension.class)
public @interface Stepwise {}
```

**Feature methods declared in super- and subspecs are not affected.**

The test methods are called feature methods in Spock. So everything's fine, because it works this way by design.

If you want to fail your test suit when a parent test fails, add a custom listerner to the child test:

```
@Stepwise
class Child extends Parent {

    def setupSpec() {
        def spec = this.getSpecificationContext().currentSpec
        spec.addListener(new AbstractRunListener() {
            @Override
            void error(ErrorInfo error) {
                spec.features.each { it.skipped = true }
            }
        })
    }

    def "test"() {
        given:
        println "Child::test#1"
    }

    def "test#2"() {
        given:
        println "Child::test#2"
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to skip the tests of child?

Comment: Add a custom listener. I added an example of such listener to my answer.

Comment: Please share your code. Here is mine and it works - https://github.com/angry-cellophane/spock-examples/blob/master/src/test/groovy/org/ka/inheritance/Child.groovy

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentSpec for class: org.spockframework.runtime.SpecificationContext
 at com.target.functional.utils.Child.setupSpec(Child.groovy:18)

i am getting following exception.

Comment: What if we have other class "SubClass" which extends Childs then i have added listsner in that class as well . the logic is not also not working in that case.That means still methods of Child is gettting executed.